# How to deal with Vba runtime error "1004": Application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

[The Yellow Line is where error occurs][1]

Help me debug and know possible cause of error '1004' in vba
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHOwG.png

Comment: Please don't post your code in image, you can easily paste it in your question. Please edit and include in your question

Comment: Are your named ranges really sheet-local and not global names?

Comment: Could you have a read of [ASK] and [MCVE] please and as @RaymondWu said - please don't post code as an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.